# Force Google Chrome to use computer's geolocation

Tags: google-chrome, geolocation

I'm trying to get the location of an HP EliteBook. (in google maps and just clicking on "your position").

With Microsoft Edge I get it very precisely. 
With Firefox and Chrome I have an accuracy of about 30 meters which is far too much. I managed to fix it with Firefox by changing configuration in about:config and setting geo.provider.ms-windows-location to true.

Is there any equivalent option in Chrome, I can't find anything.

Thank you.

Comment: Interesting question. My gut sense is Chrome's not going to allow an alternate geolocation provider because they value the wifi SSID data they get by using their own service.